# How to display Image and Read more link with description from Announcement List?

Tags: newsfeed, sharepoint-list, announcements

I have a requirement that News and announcements which are added in announcemnts list should be displayed in home page with Image at the left and Description followed by Read more Link if the description size is increses.

And it should have slider which contains 3 news per slide

Please help me with the code samples and steps as i am new to custom page design.

Kind Regards,
Peter Solomon

Comment: take a look at JSLink slider examples.

Answer (score 0):

Bind Image at the left from the attachment of an announcement list item and set anchor tag, which have the URL of the detail page with the announcement ID in query string, on the Read more link if the description is having more length.

Use a jQuery Slider Carousal to display news in a slide.